# Ubuntu 12.04.4 x64 - How to disable SSH daemon

Tags: security

I've read in this thread that running the SSH daemon with root privileges enabled by default is a potential path for malware infections:

[How to deal with malware on my laptop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/440919/how-to-deal-with-malware-on-my-laptop)

How can I check whether the SSH daemon is enabled, and if this is the case, how can I disable it permanently? I think I don't need it at all because my computer on which Ubuntu is running is not used as a server.

Comment: It's not installed by default, and if it's installed then root login is disabled by default. I guess, I really don't understand what you're asking.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I do not think you are understanding the thread you linked or the ssh server. In the thread you linked, the OP had been cracked, likely because of a weak password, but we do not know. As a result, a cracked server called sshd was installed and running. This is not the same thing as the ssh server in the ubuntu repositories.

By default, the ssh server is not installed or running on Ubuntu, so unless you installed it, it is not installed or running.

Also, by default, the root account is locked. So unless you unlocked it, even if you have the ssh server installed and running, root can not log in.

See: https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/openssh-server.html

and

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Configuring

and

**https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo**

and

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BasicSecurity

To check if the server is installed:

```
sudo dpkg -l | grep ssh
```

To see if it, or any other server, is running, run

```
sudo netstat -ntulp
```